# How can we use python module in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to use the python module imaplib, email in vb.net to read the gmail email with attachments. How can i use the python module in vb.net

Comment: Why do you want to use a Python module?  Why not use something directly in .NET?  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx

Comment: Yes I can use the imaplibrary in .Net. But can i read the mail with the attachments using that library

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you already looked at Brad's suggestion and didn't find it quite satisfying [there is a .Net module](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html) for handling python, although this seems like the inverse of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you could realistically use a Python library in .NET is to use IronPython. It is possible to embed IronPython in a C# app and the best explanation of that is in the book [IronPython in Action](http://www.ironpythoninaction.com/).

However, this introduces a lot of layers in an application and may not be the wisest way to go unless you can make use of a general scripting language in your app.